# run grunt in mangeto 2

Tags: magento2, error, grunt

Already follow from this dev document [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/tools/using_grunt.html)

1.npm install -g grunt-cli

2.Rename 3 files
 - package.json.sample into package.json 
 - Gruntfile.js.sample into Gruntfile.js 
 - grunt-config.json.sample into grunt-config.json

3.cd your_Magento_instance_directory
  npm install
  npm update

4.adding themes in dev/tools/grunt/configs themes.js

```
 default: {
    area: 'frontend',
    name: 'Tutor/default',
    locale: 'en_US',
    files: [
        'css/styles-m',
        'css/styles-l'
    ],
    dsl: 'less'
}
```

however Im using linux ubuntu 16.0, Im running command grunt in magento root folder

Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR

> > Error: Cannot find module '/home/user/www/tutor/dev/tools/grunt/configs/local-themes'
> >     Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

anybody know about this error.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please mentioned the command you are running.

Comment: @SaphalJha in root my magento2 $grunt

Comment: Is simple 'grunt' command is working?

Comment: i tried $grunt only error Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
Warning: Task "default" not found. Used --force, continuing.
i tried also $grunt --force still same error

Answer (score 1):

please check the file "**grunt-config.json**" file in your project root folder. following code should be there:

```
{
    "themes": "dev/tools/grunt/configs/local-themes"
}
```

Also, please check the location **/home/user/www/tutor/dev/tools/grunt/configs**

There will be the file is "**themes.js**", please rename it to "**local-themes.js**"

flush the cache

Please check now and let me now if its working. However, I am sure it will be working for you.

Thanks

Comment: Im already follow your steps still error dude Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not rename this, keep it as default :

```
grunt-config.json.sample
```

Now try again, if not working then add `--force` after your command

Comment: already rename it to default grunt-config.json.sample, in my magento root my command  $grunt but still error Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
Warning: Task "default" not found. Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.
already add --force in my command still same $grunt --force

Comment: Did you tried above solution.

Comment: Im already tried as your suggestion but still error

Answer (score 0):

**Define Like this :-**

```
<theme>: {
     area: 'frontend',
     name: '<Vendor>/<theme>',  // app/Design/Frontend/Vendor/Theme/ 
     locale: '<language>',
     files: [
         'css/styles-m',
         'css/styles-l'
     ],
     dsl: 'less'
     }
```

Comment: already my define as my first description

Comment: change "default" to your "theme name"

Comment: my theme name is default :D and my vendor is Tutor

Comment: re-installing grunt  "sudo npm install grunt"

Comment: i did re-installing stiil same error

Comment: completely reinstalling grunt and npm

Comment: i did already 2 times

Answer (score 0):

Here is process for installing grunt:

First Rename files from root directory - package.json.sample into package.json - Gruntfile.js.sample into Gruntfile.js

1. Install NodeJs from https://nodejs.org/
2. Once you have Node install properly run command: "sudo npm install -g grunt-cli"
3. Go to your project dir. then run command: "sudo npm install grunt --save-dev"
4. then: "npm install"
5. Now run command "grunt"

Comment: 1 already install my node js is v4.2.6
2 already install also mya grunt is grunt-cli v1.3.2 and grunt v1.0.4
3.already running sudo npm install grunt --save-dev and also npm install when running command $grunt error like this - Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Alhamdulillah, my issues solve
I just updating my nodejs, because my nodjs before the old one so im updating

1. sudo npm install -g n
2. sudo n latest

Done, I can run $grunt , $grunt exec:mytheme

Thanks you all for any sugestion :D

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had when I got the "unexpected token" error was because one of the theme/sections in my themes.js or local-themes.js contained a hyphen. For example:

```
theme-frontend-PS: {
     area: 'frontend',
     name: 'PS/theme-frontend-PS',  // app/Design/Frontend/Vendor/Theme/ 
     locale: '<language>',
     files: [
         'css/styles-m',
         'css/styles-l'
     ],
     dsl: 'less'
 }
```

This would result in an error. Instead, I renamed "theme-frontend-PS" at the beginning of the block to "PS", but you can leave the actual name of the theme alone. Like this:

```
PS: {
     area: 'frontend',
     name: 'PS/theme-frontend-PS',  // app/Design/Frontend/Vendor/Theme/ 
     locale: '<language>',
     files: [
         'css/styles-m',
         'css/styles-l'
     ],
     dsl: 'less'
 }
```